# If a certain value is equal to yx^2, how do you find the value of x and y in python while both x and y are integers

Tags: python, sympy

```py
import sympy

def find_integer_values(value):
  x, y = sympy.symbols('x y', integer=True)
  equation = sympy.Eq(y * x**2, value)         

  # Solve for integer values of x and y
  solutions = sympy.solve(equation, (x, y), dict=True)

  # Filter solutions to include only integers
  integer_solutions = [(sol[x], sol[y]) for sol in solutions if sympy.simplify(sol[x]).is_integer and sympy.simplify(sol[y]).is_integer]
 
  return integer_solutions

# Example usage:
given_value = 1920

integer_solutions = find_integer_values(given_value)

if integer_solutions:
  print("Integer solutions for x and y:", integer_solutions)
else:
  print("No integer solutions found.")
```

The code is supposed to find the values of x and y which are both integers. But there is something wrong with this part of the code-
`integer_solutions = [(sol[x], sol[y]) for sol in solutions if sympy.simplify(sol[x]).is_integer and sympy.simplify(sol[y]).is_integer]`

Any advice on how I can fix this is much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at sympy's [Diophantine module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html)

Comment: "But there is something wrong with this part of the code" - **How do you know**? When you try this code, **what happens**? What do you think **should** happen instead, and **how is that different**?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to split a number into a square part and a non-square part. This boils down to factoring the number:

```py
def mysolve(value):
    from sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine import square_factor
    # return values for x*y**2 = value
    from sympy.abc import x, y
    s = square_factor(value)
    return {x: value//s**2, y:s}

>>> mysolve(1920)
{x: 30, y: 8}
>>> 30*8**2
1920
```

If `s` is 1 you could raise an error.